# Where exactly in IPFS.create() or IPFS.add() does my node propagate an updated distributed hash table upon adding a file?

Tags: bootstrapping, ipfs, dht, js-ipfs

Original question: [Does the IPFS.add() method automatically update my local DHT and propagate it to other peers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73678087/does-the-ipfs-add-method-automatically-update-my-local-dht-and-propagate-it-to)

In order to test whether the IPFS.add() method alone allows other peers to download content from a my pc, I ran this script on my windows pc:

```
import * as IPFS from "ipfs";

const node = await IPFS.create();
var file = await node.add("Shiiiiiiiiiiitttt");
```

and ran this code on my macbook to fetch the file:

```
import * as IPFS from "ipfs";
const node = await IPFS.create();
//fetching Shiiiiiiiiiiitttt
const stream = node.cat("QmetK5x9nLUG5jDwp7Un25n47exuNjDZ3cKvnKfC6Hebmi")
 
const decoder = new TextDecoder()
let data = ''
 
for await (const chunk of stream) {
 // chunks of data are returned as a Uint8Array, convert it back to a string
 data += decoder.decode(chunk, { stream: true })
 console.log("decoding")
}
 
//At the end, as long as ipfs is running in owner node, there was no need for ipfs.dht.provide method call
 
console.log(data)
```

What I found out through this test was that as long as I keep running jsipfs daemon or the script itself on the windows pc that adds a file or text, I can retrieve it from other devices using IPFS.cat(). This confuses me deeply, since IPFS also has a separate method, IPFS.dht.provide(), and my current understanding of IPFS dictates that an updated dht propagation to other peers is necessary to enable them to fetch files. However, from my test, I can logically conclude that there has to be some method within IPFS.add() that propagates an updated distributed hash table or at least a similar alternative to other peers so that they know I have the file. I'm having a very difficult time finding these source methods for automatic dht propagation upon adding a file and would appreciate any help on finding the said methods or an under-the-hood explanation of what happens during IPFS.add() .

Answer (score -1):

Check out the ipfs docks https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/ , far more important than you first think.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).